# Uma duvida sobre python PyAutoGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, automatização, pyautogui

Por acaso e possível eu usar o PyAutoGUI em um navegador que não esta aparecendo na tela ?Tipo eu criar um código para o PyAutoGUI trabalhar com as coordenadas de um navegador especifico(ex: Firefox) enquanto eu visualizo outras coisas na tela(ex:ver video do youtube) em outro navegador(ex: Opera) ?

o que eu quero fazer e dar um click em um determinado local a cada 5 minutos +ou- e essa operação e rápida porem o intervalo entre elas não é. Não importa eu perder o controle do mouse nesses milissegundos o que eu não queria era ter que deixar a tela aberta na tela

ps: Me desculpem se eu não soube me expressar muito bem.

Desde já agradeço e desculpem a ignorância.

Answer (score 1):

O PyAutoGUI na verdade não sabe o que está aparecendo na tela, o que ele faz é automatizar o funcionamento do mouse e do teclado. Se você pretende clicar em um navegador específico (inclusive headless) recomendo que tente a biblioteca do Selenium. O PyAutoGUI vai clicar no lugar em que você mapear o clique INDEPENDENTE do que é que está aparecendo naquela posição da tela.

Comment: Precisamente - usar selenium é a recomendação correta neste caso.